# GridView getView Issue

Tags: java, android, gridview, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

In the getView() method of my GridView, I am doing the following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       convertView = this.inflater.inflate(..);
       ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
       imageLoader.displayImage("URL/"
                + sampleArray.get(position), image);
```

sampleArray here is an array I've loaded when the Adapter is created. It is used when lazy-loading (with this tool: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) these images and basically is a part of the image URL that determines the picture to load. Now, as far as I know, best practice is to do *only inflate the view* if it's null:

```
if(convertView == null){
   this.inflater.inflate(...);
```

When I do this, it is infact faster, but the image loading is weird. If I scroll down and scroll back up, the images switch within the row, meaning in the top row, the 1st column image might randomly switch with the second column image. The array I am using (sampleArray) doesn't change. I know it has something to do with position and getView() being called, but I'm not sure why this behavior happens.

If I do it the way I am doing now (the first block of code), meaning I inflate it every time, it works perfectly but loads slowly. Why does this behavior work like this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

Here's what I think is happening. GetView() is being called multiple times, which is somehow not in sync with the "position" argument, causing the wrong element to be picked out of the array. I'm still puzzled by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
.resetViewBeforeLoading()
```

and probably

```
.showStubImage(R.drawable.empty_image)
```

on your DisplayImageOptions when you initialize the UIL.
This will reset the view before the loading.
This is needed because you are reusing the views on gridview.

Comment: isn't your answer duplicated with mine? please check my answer: I think you can also try to set the option as "resetViewBeforeLoading = true"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean up the original image:

```
image.setImageBitmap(null);
```

I check the source code of the [image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoader.java%22image%20loader%22), one of the methods is like:

```
public void displayImage(String uri, ImageView imageView, DisplayImageOptions options)
```

I think you can also try to set the option as "resetViewBeforeLoading = true"

the reason I think that the weird thing happens is, the view is recycled by the gridview, which is still with the original bitmap when showing up, before the loader attach it with the new bitmap.

if it still doesn't work, please lemme know.

**EDIT**

I did more investigation, the reason I think is from the recycling.
Let me explain more clearly:

*reason:*

suppose we have total 12 cells in our data
on screen, there are only 9 views visible

at very beginning, the gridview will create and show 9 on screen:

view_1_1 view_1_2 view_1_3

view_2_1 view_2_2 view_2_3

view_3_1 view_3_2 view_3_3

after scrolling(scrolling up, to show the row 4), at the moment, grid view will put view_1_1, view_1_2, view_1_3 in recycle bin.
and then will get 3 views for row 4 from recycle-bin, which are put in the getView as "convertView"
so, the view_1_1, view_1_2, view_1_3 will be reused.

suppose at the beginning, the views are attached with bitmap

view_1_1 : bitmap_1_1

view_1_2 : bitmap_1_2

view_1_3 : bitmap_1_3

when these view are recycled and show at the row 4, since the bitmaps are loaded asynchronously, the bitmap_1_1, bitmap_1_2, bitmap_1_3 will show up on the row 4, and laterly be replaced by those new bitmap.

*how to confirm it*

1.one way for debugging grid view I like is put some "id" on the image, the simple way is just put "ImageView" toString()
put an overlay view above each imageView, and write id in it, like:

```
String s = viewInfoHolder.imageView.toString();
viewInfoHolder.overlay.setText(s.substring(s.length() -3));//last 3 chars are enough and cleanup
```

2.for making the replacement slow, modify the

```
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask
```

the last row in method:

```
public void run()
```

from:

```
handler.post(displayBitmapTask);
```

to:

```
handler.postDelayed(displayBitmapTask, 2000);
```

and you could find out exactly how the grid view works.

Hope it helpful :)

Comment: unfortunately, not working (again, it's fast with the convertView==null check,but images switch randomly) . Please see my question's edit for a possible thought.